# hash table/ unordered map in C++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, hash, hashtable

I am looking for a template for hash map that i can rely on, and use whenever i need hash table. I was trying to use hash_map but found out that it is deprecated now.Tried using unordered_map, but i get the following error-

```
error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ s        tandard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -s    td=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

Now, i am completely confused. I have been using hashmap in java, and it was pleasantly straight forward. It is not so in c++.
Guide me on what to use and how to use a hash table in c++.

Comment: Well, many things are not ˝pleasantly stright forward¨ in C++ as they are in Java. Officially, unordered_map and unordered_set were included in the tr1 extension, so there is a chance that gnu provides a c++03 implementation without c++01 features activated. In this case you should be able to use std::tr1::unordered_map after including <unordered_map>

Comment: I forgot: You might want to install boost. It provides a transparently usable implementation of tr1 including the hash-tables based solely on c++03 features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hash_map` (or rather, `unordered_map`, as it was called to avoid name collisions) is in the latest version of C++ (c++0x, or c++11) but many compilers, including yours, supported it before that. Your compiler is just being nice and stopping you from writing potentially non-portable code without your explicit consent.

As the others say, adding `-std=c++0x` to your compiler options will allow you to use hash_map,

Do be aware that compiling that code somewhere else will require a rather modern c++ compiler.
(That might not be an issue for you.. if you're just learning by yourself or not sharing the code outside your office, you should be fine...)

Comment: hash_map isn't in C++0x, they called it unordered_map specifically to avoid collissions with the many not-quite-compatible compiler-specific hash_map implementations. Other than the name it's basically the same thing though.

Comment: @Sven: Right you are. I should'be mentioned that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

Do what the error message says, invoke g++ as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++0x
```

Followed by the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Just use -std=c++0x when you compile like your error message says! Anyhow the normal [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) interface in C++ is fairly optimized so unless performance is absolutely critical you should just use the [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) container.

Comment: I require hash table, map won;t serve the purpose1